# How to declare pointer from struct to final array

Tags: c, pointers

I want to make an array of struct, the problem is when to each single struct has different size of array.
I tried to make an pointer to the array, but i dont get the point.

```
typedef struct {

    char *opcodeName;

    int   opcodeNumber;

    int   howManyOprendsNeeded;

    int   *sourceAddressingMode;

    int   *destAddressingMode;

}Opcode;
```

```
typedef enum {

  IMMEDIATE, DIRECT, INDEX, REGISTER

}ADDRESSING_MODE;
```

```
static const Opcode opcodes[] = {

        {"mov", 0, 2, {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER},{DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}   },
        {"cmp" ,1, 2, {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}, {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}},
        {"add" ,2, 2, {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER},{DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER }    },
        {"sub" ,3, 2, {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER},{ DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}   },
        {"not" ,4, 1, {-1}                                   , {DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}  },
        {"clr" ,5, 1, {-1}                                   , {DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER} },
        {"lea" ,6, 2, {DIRECT,INDEX}                         , {DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}   },
        {"inc" ,7, 1, {-1}                                   , {DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER} },
        {"dec" ,8, 1, {-1}                                   , {DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER} },
        {"jmp" ,9, 1, {-1}                                   , {DIRECT ,REGISTER}  },
        {"bne" ,10, 1,{-1}                                   , {DIRECT , REGISTER}  },
        {"red" ,11, 1,{-1}                                   ,  {DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}  },
        {"prn" ,12, 1,{-1}                                   , {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}  },
        {"jsr" ,13, 1,{-1}                                   , {DIRECT , REGISTER}  },
        {"rts" ,14, 0,{-1}                                  , {-1}},
        {"stop",15, 0,{-1}                                  , {-1}},


};
```

How can i declare the array from the strcut, If i dont know how much the size is.
The errors i got : 
1.initialization of 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] causing by {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}.
2.excess elements in scalar initializer. causing by {-1}.

Comment: You can't initialize pointers like that. It could be possible using [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to make the pointer point to an array (e.g. `(int[]){ ... }`), but then this initialization must be at file-scope or else the array will end its life when the block it's defined in ends.

Comment: The easiest solution is to let `sourceAddressingMode` and `destAddressingMode` be arrays of a fixed maximum size. Then use as much of them as needed. They are not arrays currently, but pointers, which doesn't make sense given this initializer list you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off all, i think when i tied to compile your code i had so much warning, if i were you i would try to avoid those, wall warning are not bugs, but some are and are a good way to debug.
most errors are:
`incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int'`

One possibily that would make a lot of sense to me would be, as you know in advance thse size of your arrays to declare them this way:

```
int   sourceAddressingMode[4];

int   destAddressingMode[4];
```

but is not optimal.

The best to me would be using binary operators:

your opcode become:

```
typedef enum {

IMMEDIATE 0, DIRECT 1, INDEX 2, REGISTER 4

}ADDRESSING_MODE;
```

your sourceAddressingMode and destAddressingMode are of type int.

declaration is quite easy and looks like

```
{"mov", 0, 2, {IMMEDIATE | DIRECT | INDEX | REGISTER},{DIRECT | INDEX | REGISTER}   },
```

and to know for exemple of your first opCode have a sourceAddressingMode that is DIRECT, you can use  the '&' operator such has:

```
if (Opcode[0].sourceAddressingMode & DIRECT)
  //do stuff
```

hope that will help, and i ll be glad to know what kiran Biradar does think about this solution instead of casts. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat initialization elements as compound literals if you want to assign it to pointer.

**Example:**

change

```
{"mov", 0, 2, {IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER},{DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}   },
```

to

```
{"mov", 0, 2, (int []){IMMEDIATE ,DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}, (int []){DIRECT , INDEX , REGISTER}   },
```

> Note:: `(int [])` will be having local scope and accessing them
>   outside its scope is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note the `static` qualifier. If this is a local `static` variable you can't initialize it to point at compound literals. It will only work in case it is declared at file scope.

Comment: In regard to the note: `(int [])` has no scope because it has no name. Scope is **where** in source code an **identifier** is visible. Lifetime is **when** during program execution an **object** exists. The statement that an object cannot be accessed “outside its scope” is false because an object may be accessed by subroutines called during its lifetime.